# SQL VB.net insert using select AND values

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql

New to using SQL and I am having trouble accomplishing something that I figured would be simple.

I am trying to create and INSERT that will insert the MAX() value from the first column in one table to the first column in another table while the rest of the columns will be filled with parameters.

I have tried switching my code around to see if I just had the syntax wrong but I've had no luck and I'm not even sure what I'm trying to do is possible (at least in a single INSERT).

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
INSERT INTO [Table2] VALUES(SELECT(Number FROM [Table1] WHERE Max(Number)), @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10)
```

Comment: try creating the script in Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) first and then work it into your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the select statement must be enclosed in parentheses and I recommend you always put the list of columns in the insert statement

```
Insert into [MyTable] (Max,Value1,Value2,Value3) values((select Max(Number) from Table1),@p1,@p2,@p3)
```

Comment: Ahh, damn parentheses.  Thanks for your help, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First: The *SELECT MAX* statement is wrong, the correct syntax is:

```
SELECT Max(Number) From [Table1]
```

Second: the *INSERT* syntax is wrong. To use a subquery you have to select values for every field in the destination table, while if you use the **VALUES** keyword you have to specify the field to insert the value in.

So your query have to became something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Table2] 
SELECT Max(Number), @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10 From [Table1]
```

OR (i'm using lesser parameter for practical reason)

```
INSERT INTO [Table2] (field1,field2,field3)
VALUES
(@MAX, @p1, @p2)
```

where @MAX is a variable containing the result of

```
SELECT Max(Number) From [Table1]
```